# Eager Loading in Laravel 5.2 is not working

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5, eager-loading

I researched related to this question but didn't work on my situation. I'm studying Laravel 5.2 for now to learn my first framework. But I encountered this problem in the tutorial which is using "Eager Loading".

I'm not sure if *Card Model* and *Table* are needed but just to make sure I added them.

**What I'm trying to do?**
I want to display the user that is associated with the note.

---

**These are my codes and files**

**CardsController.php**

```
public function show(Card $card)
{

    return $card->notes[0]->user;

}
```

---

**TABLES:**

**User**

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Notes**

```
Schema::create('notes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('card_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Cards**

```
Schema::create('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

---

**MODELS:** 
`namespace` and `use` are just the same to the other models that are blank

**User.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Note::class);
    }
}
```

**Note.php**

```
class Note extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body'];

    public function card()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Card::class);
    }
}
```

**Card.php**

```
class Card extends Model
{
    public function notes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
    }

    public function addNote(Note $note)
    {
        return $this->notes()->save($note);
    }
}
```

---

**Expected Output:**

[Expected Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ypsn.png)

**My Output:**

My output is blank. The browser didn't show anything.

---

Let me know if you see a missing code coz I shortened the `CardsController.php` because I think that code is the important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly pop-up in my mind while thinking of the solution. This solved my problem. I just added the code below in `User.php` model. And it worked like magic.

```
 public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Note::class);
    }
```